# Dataframe List Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning,

I have the following List.

[    Unnamed: 0   R$/m3 Var./Dia Var./Mês
0   12/03/2021  2.9820   -0,03%    3,38%
1   11/03/2021  2.9830   -0,10%    3,41%
2   10/03/2021  2.9860    0,29%    3,52%
3   09/03/2021  2.9775   -0,02%    3,22%
4   08/03/2021  2.9780    0,25%    3,24%
5   05/03/2021  2.9705   -0,60%    2,98%
6   04/03/2021  2.9885   -0,05%    3,61%
7   03/03/2021  2.9900    0,57%    3,66%
8   02/03/2021  2.9730    3,07%    3,07%
9   01/03/2021  2.8845    0,00%    0,00%
10  26/02/2021  2.8845    2,72%   30,94%
11  25/02/2021  2.8080    1,10%   27,46%
12  24/02/2021  2.7775    1,67%   26,08%
13  23/02/2021  2.7320    2,11%   24,01%
14  22/02/2021  2.6755    1,02%   21,45%]

Read from

esalq_dia = pd.read_html('https://www.cepea.esalq.usp.br/br/indicador/etanol-diario-paulinia.aspx')

I'm having trouble to converitng into dataframe

cols = ['Unnamed: 0',  'R$/litro',  'US$/litro', 'Var./semana']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(esalq_dia, columns=cols)

Returns only this. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
Unnamed: 0  R$/litro    US$/litro   Var./semana
```

0   Unnamed: 0  R$/m3   Var./Dia    Var./Mês

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlX5r.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
esalq_dia = pd.read_html('https://www.cepea.esalq.usp.br/br/indicador/etanol-diario-paulinia.aspx')
esalq_dia[0]
```

Comment: For more context : read_html return list of dataframe, since your original data only contain 1 sheet(i think), it will return a list with length 1. So we just need to get the first element. While printing the list seems like it is a string, don't trust what you see easily, and start to use type() function to debug your code